# How to re-trigger Jenkins for a pull request after giving a specific comment in a pull request

Tags: jenkins

I want to understand how to re-trigger a Jenkins pipeline for a pull request after I leave a comment such as "Rebuild" in this pull request.

In order to re-trigger this job, the commit_sha and the other information will be needed.
But in this case only a comment from the response of webhook, it contains no information about commit_sha and pull_request_title

My generic trigger looks like this:

```
triggers {
                genericTrigger {
                    genericVariables {
                        genericVariable {
                            key("action")
                            value("\$.action")
                            expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
                            regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
                            defaultValue("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
                        }
                        genericVariable {
                            key("commit_sha")
                            value("\$.pull_request.head.sha")
                            expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
                            regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
                            defaultValue("\$commit_sha") //Optional, defaults to empty string
                        }
```

the question is, how can I realize the following; If I only leave a comment the Jenkins job will be re-triggered.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the contents of a commit and changing pipeline behaviour based on the content might be challenging. I would approach this by accessing the author or commit message. Like

```
def author = sh(script: 'git show -s --format="%an"', returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "Author of latest commit: ${author}"
```

to access the author and change pipeline behaviour this way

Comment: where should this command be used?